# Storybook: Angular add provider at component level

Tags: angular, storybook

Is is possible to add a provider in Storybook for an Angular component, but at the host level?

For example, if we have this two components:

```
@Component({
  selector: "child-cmp",
  template: "<p>Hello</p>",
})
class ChildCmp {
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() parentCmp: ParentCmp) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: "parent-cmp",
  template: "<child-cmp></child-cmp>",
})
class ParentCmp {}
```

The `ChildCmp` is searching for `ParentCmp`. [Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) decorator is used, thus it stops at the host element.

In testing this is achieved with `overrideComponent`.

```
testBed.overrideComponent(ChildCmp, {
  add: {
    providers: [{ provide: ParentCmp, useValue: {} }],
  },
});
```

There is something similar for Storybook, as I understand, Storybook will create a module to render the component and the providers are added at the module level.

This is the Storybook configuration, but here the provider is at the module level and is only available if the `Host` decorator is removed, which isn't desired.

```
const Template: Story<ChildCmp> = (args: ChildCmp) => ({
  props: args,
  template: `<child-cmp></child-cmp>`,
  moduleMetadata: {
    providers: [
      {
        provide: ParentCmp,
        useValue: {},
      },
    ],
  },
});

export const ChildCmp = Template.bind({});
```